# css inline styles safari on facebook fan page

Tags: html, css, facebook-page

I want to use CSS to create rounded-corners on facebook fan-page. I have created the fanpage but I can't get the styles to work for safari browser. I have used to Safari Development tools and when I do the in-line styles it actually works but when I go and put it in the fbml code, nothing updates in safari. I have also included the same style in a stylesheet which is hosted somewhere else and it doesn't work. any help would be appreciated.

*My CSS for rounded-corners*

`-webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;

-moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;

    -khtml-border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;

    border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;

    -moz-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;

    box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;

    padding-left: 5px;

    padding-right: 5px;

    background: #DAE1EB;

    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#DAE1EB), to(#DAE1EB));

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#DAE1EB, #DAE1EB);

    background: linear-gradient(#DAE1EB, #DAE1EB);

    -pie-background: linear-gradient(#DAE1EB, #DAE1EB);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Try this:

In the src of your CSS after is says `.css` try putting `.css?2`  (any number).

I've had some problems with FB caching and it's CDN, this usually solves it.

Let me know if this helps.